# Can I craft a statement to return records where (attribute A = A1 and attribute B = B1) OR (attrbt A = A2 and attrbt B = B2) OR etc etc?

Tags: mysql, sql

User has given me a table of vendor #s and Invoice #s, and wants a query to find the documents with those attributes. Tried just giving him:

```
select * from document.docdata
join document.documents.vendor #s
join document.documents.invoice #s
Where 
vendor # in (paste in column A from his table)
AND
invoice # in (paste in column b from his table)
```

But that didn't do the trick, because he's wanting to see the docs whose vendor# and invoice# match the rows of the table, as in vendor#, invoice# = A1, B1. My first question was "Why not just search by the invoice# and be done with it?"
But turns out the invoice numbers aren't unique.

So I'm needing a better way of writing this:

```
Select * from table
join vendor #s
join invoice #s
Where
(Vendor#=A1 AND Invoice#=B1)
OR
(Vendor#=A2 AND Invoice#=B2)
....
OR
(Vendor#=A652 AND Invoice#=B652)
```

For sample data, here's an example with the first 10 items from the user. I have this data in csv format.

```
   A    |    B
---------------------
354055  |  1637
259769  |  2112
259769  |  2314
153060  |  47185
174829  |  63486
297719  |  4994-033017
203110  |  1360
292193  |  2058-09-1271
202308  |  60513 
286641  |  1975
```

So I need the records that match both Company 354055 and Invoice 1637, as well as both Company 259769 and Invoice 2112, plus both Company 259769 and Invoice 2314, etc.

EDIT: I ended up just using excel to get 659 lines of "(Vendor#=x AND Invoice#=y) OR".  Probably could run faster but it works, so off to production it goes.

Comment: Please tag your question with the actual database product you're using. `SQL` is a standard, not a language. [Why should I “tag my RDBMS”?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/388759/why-should-i-tag-my-rdbms) That doesn't look like valid SQL in any dialect that I'm familiar with.

Comment: Are you looking for `where (vendor, invoice) in ( (a1,b1), (a2, b2), ...)`?

Comment: a_horse_with_no_name - Yes, and that might be the best I can get.  I was really hoping for a solution that didn't require (a1,b1), (a2,b2) etc all the way to (a652, b652), but I could potentially reach that formatting through some excel functions.

Comment: Things may have changed or I may simply be mistaken, but I seem to remember that MySQL struggles to use indexes when written that way ^^^

Answer (score 0):

This is a rough answer, since we don't have good sample data or column names, but the general idea is, since you have an external table that matches invoice #s to vendor #s, you should *import that data into a temporary table*. Then you can join against the table for records where both conditions match in an efficient way.

There are also [`VALUES()` expressions](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/values.html) (formally: Table Value Constructors). You could use this to generate your query with a little less code: create the expression for your data as part of the SQL string, and then `JOIN` against that expression to accomplish the filter.

```
SELECT d.* 
FROM document.docdata d
INNER JOIN (
    VALUES 
        ROW(354055,'1637'),
        ROW(259769,'2112'),
        ROW(259769,'2314'),
        ROW(153060,'47185')
        -- etc
) filter on filter.invoice = d.invoice and filter.company = d.company
```

Comment: So for sample data, both of these columns are just numbers.  Here are the first 10 entries of both columns:

Vendor #s
354055
259769
259769
153060
174829
297719
203110
292193
202308
286641

Invoice #s
1637
2112
2314
47185
63486
4994-033017
1360
2058-09-1271
60513
1975

Column names would be table.Vendor#s, table.Invoice#s

Comment: Don't put them here. Put them in your question.

Comment: I'm not sure why?  They might as well be random numbers, they'd just make my question look more chaotic.

Comment: Edited the question, think I understand what you were asking for now.

Comment: @Banjornin I updated your question with what we expect to see for this kind of thing.

Answer (score 0):

MySQL supports tuple syntax:

```
Select *
from table join
     vendor #s
     on . . . join 
     invoice #s
     on . . .
Where (#Vendor#, Invoice#) in ( (A1, B1), (A2, B2), . . . )
```

Comment: It looks like this might be the best I can get.  I was hoping to find a solution where I could just paste in the csv for each column, as opposed to having to format out each (A1, B1).....(A652, B652), but looks like that might not be a possibility.

Comment: Tried this out but was getting a non-boolean error for the comma after 
    "Where (Vendor#"

Comment: @Banjomin . . . MySQL definitely supports `in` with tuples:  https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/comparison-operators.html#operator_in.